# Multiple OpenGL Viewports with Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I would like to render a 3D scene into different viewports. Those viewports are included in "subwindows" with their own menus like this:
[image]

Each viewport can be:

- Resized;
- Hidden;
- Displayed in full screen;
- Moved to another part of the application.

So we can have something like:
[image]

I believe it is better to embed each viewport into a Qt Widget containing my OpenGL widget (is that right?). So **how can I render my 3D scene into several Qt OpenGL Widgets?**

Comment: I'm curious, does the Qt widget provide all the "View", "Shading", "Lighting" options by itself? What's the name of this widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I believe it is better to embed each viewport into a Qt Widget containing my OpenGL widget (is that right?).So how can I render my 3D scene into several Qt OpenGL Widgets?

As described in [QGlWidget's detailed description](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglwidget.html#details), besides overriding initializeGL and paintGL, you also need to override the [resizeGL](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglwidget.html#resizeGL) method. In the resizeGL method, you need to adjust the view port, and frustum.

After that, it is just a matter of creating and placing the widgets on the screen. They can be completely independent of each other, and you can set the frustum differently for each.

Since you want to share the opengl context between these widgets, take a look into [OpenGL context sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qopenglcontext.html#context-resource-sharing). To actually do it, you need to pass the OpenGL context object as the first parameter to the constructor of the [QGLWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#QGLWidget-2).

Comment: Thanks for your anser. If I have 8 QGlWidget, rendering one 3D scene, then I need to init OpenGL (VAOs, VBOs, etc) only once. How can I then "share" the initialization (and rendering?) between those 8 different objects?

Comment: @Korchkidu By using a common OpenGL context. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qopenglcontext.html#context-resource-sharing

Comment: @Korchkidu Also, you need to create QGLWidget with specific context object : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#QGLWidget-2

Comment: Excellent! Seems much more easy than I first imagined;) Please integrate both comments to your answer + edit the links to point to the 5.1 documentation, and I will accept your answer. The links to 5.1 are (in order of appearence hopefully): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglwidget.html | http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglwidget.html#resizeGL | http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglcontext.html#context-resource-sharing | http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglwidget.html#QGLWidget-2

Comment: I know the question is specifically for Qt 5, but just in case some one stumbles upon this for Qt 6, `QOpenGLWidget` no longer accepts a `QOpenGLContext` parameter in its constructor.  Sharing is facilitated by `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, true);` which needs to be done before `QApplication` instantiation.  Check [QOpenGLWidget documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html#context-sharing).